# Docker build for vue project module not found error

Tags: docker, vue.js

I am trying to build a vue app docker image but I keep getting this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js' in '/app'

I am using the a multi-stage dockerfile

```
FROM node:15.4 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./frontend/package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:1.19

COPY ./frontend/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here's the script section of the package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

This is a detailed log of the build process

```
[+] Building 26.9s (14/16)                                                                                                               
 => [internal] load build definition from frontend.dockerfile                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 293B                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:1.19                                                                       2.5s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:15.4                                                                        2.4s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                         0.0s
 => [auth] library/nginx:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                        0.0s
 => [build 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:15.4@sha256:a76eb778d162f8fd96138d9ca7dbd14b8916c201775a97d2f2aa22e9f13eb105            0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:1.19@sha256:df13abe416e37eb3db4722840dd479b00ba193ac6606e7902331dcea50f4f1f2         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                   8.5s
 => => transferring context: 166.03MB                                                                                               8.4s
 => CACHED [build 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/6] COPY ./frontend/package.json .                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [build 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                              0.0s
 => [build 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                            7.4s
 => ERROR [build 6/6] RUN npm run build                                                                                             8.3s
------                                                                                                                                   
 > [build 6/6] RUN npm run build:                                                                                                        
#14 2.913 
#14 2.913 > frontend@0.1.0 build
#14 2.913 > vue-cli-service build
#14 2.913 
#14 4.668 All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
```

I move the frontend folder from the project to stand alone and I am able to build the image and run a container based on it successfully.
[image]

What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: The `package.json` file and `nginx.conf` both seem to be under a `frontend` subdirectory; do you need to `COPY` that subdirectory before running the build?  I'd be surprised if your build wrote out logs in PNG format; can you edit the question to contain the actual text of the build log?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have made edits and let me explain that the nginx folder at the root of the project is not being used by the frontend. It has it's own. nginx file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243161/discussion-between-jrichardsz-and-mena).

Answer (score 0):

I try to give you some help. First of all I assume your `nginx.conf` file is located in the upper `nginx` folder. I see two in your repo. If this is the case you are copying one layer to deep. I suggest to change your file as follows with this order:

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY "frontend/target/dist" ./

FROM nginx:alpine as production
COPY ./frontend/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=build /app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

What I changed was the layer of the folders you are trying to add and the asterix (`*`) in `package.json`. If you are defining a frontend before, you are also searching it in the copied part, which is not existing in the nginx image. Also as you see you only need `/app` instead of `/app/dist`. Additional your `/etc...` config path was wrongly referenced. Give it a shot now. It should work like this with the given information I had.

Add in your `.dockerignore` file only those lines:

```
node_modules
dist
```